# How to use windows 10 Parental control APIs?

Tags: c#, winapi, windows-10

I am trying to use windows 10 parental control APIs for an application. So, have seen MSDN documentation for the APIs [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms711654%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) And also have seen a thread similar to this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177333/c-sharp-samples-for-windows-parental-controls-api) on SO. But it does not give me what I need, which is to be able to set up parental control on an account programmatically in my application.

I tried looking for code samples in the official documentation like it was suggested in the link above but I could not find any code sample to refer to on this specific topic in the windows SDK documentation. If you can just point me to a code sample, that would be good enough.

So, How do I use these Windows 10 parental control APIs in a C# program?

Comment: The samples that the documentation refers to are in the [Windows SDK](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-sdks-msdn.aspx) at `Samples\security\parentalcontrols\*`. Looking at the docs and samples, I don't see any programmatic configuration access. Admittedly, I've never dug around in this interface before, so I may not be seeing the route into it. I'll have to defer to someone else's expertise.

Comment: Since they have made APIs available, there is clearly a way for programmatic configuration access? What else could it be for? To be clear, all I want to do is to write a parental control tool using these APIs.

Comment: I forgot one word in the previous comment. I didn't see any programmatic way to **set** the configuration. I see a bunch of ways to get the settings. Sorry about that.

Comment: @Zaphod, were you able to find any examples for your needs?